# Substituting a regex only when it doesn't match another regex (Python)

Tags: python, regex

Long story short, I have two regex patterns. One pattern matches things that I want to replace, and the other pattern matches a special case of those patterns that should not be replace. For a simple example, imagine that the first one is "\{.*\}" and the second one is "\{\{.*\}\}". Then "{this}" should be replaced, but "{{this}}" should not. Is there an easy way to take a string and say "substitute all instances of the first string with "hello" so long as it is not matching the second string"?

In other words, is there a way to make a regex that is "matches the first string but not the second" easily without modifying the first string? I know that I could modify my first regex by hand to never match instances of the second, but as the first regex gets more complex, that gets very difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give replace a function ([reference](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace))

But make sure the first regex contain the second one. This is just an example:

```
regex1 = re.compile('\{.*\}')
regex2 = re.compile('\{\{.*\}\}')

def replace(match):
    match = match.group(0)
    if regex2.match(match):
        return match
    return 'replacement'


regex1.sub(replace, data)
```

Answer (score 7):

Using negative look-ahead/behind assertion

```
pattern = re.compile( "(?<!\{)\{(?!\{).*?(?<!\})\}(?!\})" )
pattern.sub( "hello", input_string )
```

Negative look-ahead/behind assertion allows you to compare against more of the string, but is not considered as using up part of the string for the match. There is also a normal look ahead/behind assertion which will cause the string to match only if the string IS followed/preceded by the given pattern.

That's a bit confusing looking, here it is in pieces:

```
"(?<!\{)"  #Not preceded by a {
"\{"       #A {
"(?!\{)"   #Not followed by a {
".*?"      #Any character(s) (non-greedy)
"(?<!\})"  #Not preceded by a } (in reference to the next character)
"\}"       #A }
"(?!\})"   #Not followed by a }
```

So, we're looking for a { without any other {'s around it, followed by some characters, followed by a } without any other }'s around it.

By using negative look-ahead/behind assertion, we condense it down to a single regular expression which will successfully match only single {}'s anywhere in the string.

Also, note that * is a greedy operator. It will match as much as it possibly can. If you use `"\{.*\}"` and there is more than one {} block in the text, everything between will be taken with it.

> "This is some example text {block1} more text, watch me disappear {block2} even more text"

becomes

> "This is some example text hello even more text"

instead of

> "This is some example text hello more text, watch me disappear hello even more text"

To get the proper output we need to make it non-greedy by appending a ?.

The python docs do a good job of presenting the re library, but the only way to really learn is to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace all the {} instances with your replacement string (which would include the {{}} ones), and then replace the {{}} ones with a back-reference to itself (overwriting the first replace with the original data) -- then only the {} instances would have changed.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to do that in python? I'm not quite sure I understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me as sub-optimal to match against two different regexes when what you're looking for is really one pattern. To illustrate:

```
import re
foo = "{{this}}"
bar = "{that}"
re.match("\{[^\{].*[^\}]\}", foo)  # gives you nothing
re.match("\{[^\{].*[^\}]\}", bar)  # gives you a match object
```

So it's really your regex which could be a bit more precise.

Comment: That's right, but Nate gave a simple imaginary example. It's not always the case.